# Failing to use CXX to link Rust-written library in C++ project

Tags: c++, rust, binding

I am testing [CXX](https://cxx.rs/index.html) with a very simple project to link a Rust library into a C++ executable.

I write a `foo() -> ()` Rust function and try to access it from C++ but the linker does not find it.

Here's what I have:

```rust
// lib.rs

#[cxx::bridge]
mod ffi {
    extern "Rust" {
        pub fn foo() -> ();
    }
}

pub fn foo() -> () {
    println!("foo")
}
```

```toml
# Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "cpprust"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
name = "cpprust"
path = "src/lib.rs"
crate-type = ["staticlib", "rlib", "dylib"] # EDIT: this is incorrect, see note at the end of question

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
cxx = "1.0"
```

```cpp
// main.cpp

void foo(); // I tried including lib.rs.h but it was not generated!

int main() {
    foo();
}
```

Running `cargo build` generates `target\debug\libcpprust.so`.
I then try to make the project with (EDIT: `g++` command is incorrect, see note at the end of question):

```plain
g++ -L../target/debug/ -lcpprust -o cpprust main.cpp
/tmp/ccOA8kJy.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `foo()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:2: cpprust] Error 1
```

What is wrong here?

**EDIT**: prog-fh's great answer correctly points out that I need to include `build.rs` with C++ compilation, even without having C++ to compile and access within the crate. However, even after implementing their answer, I was still getting the same error message. It turns out that I had two other problems: 1) the *order* of my arguments to `g++` were incorrect, and I needed `pthread -l dl` as well. It should have been:
`g++ -o cpprust main.cpp -I ../target/cxxbridge -L../target/debug -lcpprust -pthread -l dl`
2) My `Cargo.toml` file was also generating `"rlib", "dylib"` library types, but that somehow also causes the error above; it works when only `staticlib` is generated.

Comment: The tutorial says you are supposed to include `lib.rs.h` in the `.cpp` file, not declare the function yourself.

Comment: True. I tried that first, but no `.h` file was generated! I checked by running `find . -name *.h`. Why it was not generated was going to be my next question...

Comment: It also gives a section on setting up the C++ compilation: https://cxx.rs/tutorial.html#compiling-the-c-code-with-cargo. I suppose you need that as well. It seems to include the code generator.

Comment: I reasoned I did not need to include cargo-directed C++ compilation because I didn't have cpp code to be compiled by the crate. However, you and prog-fh are correct that that is still necessary, not only for generating the header file, but even for generating a library file containing the binding to the Rust code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering [this documentation](https://cxx.rs/tutorial.html#compiling-the-c-code-with-cargo), the `build.rs` script should generate the `lib.rs.h` which was missing in your attempt.

Note that the example in the documentation considers that the main program comes from Rust, and that the C++ code is an extension.
In your question, it is the opposite situation: your main program comes from C++ but is extended by some Rust code.

This answer is made of two parts:

- a minimal example very similar to yours (no C++ code to be called from Rust),
- a more complete example with a bidirectional interaction between C++ and Rust (but the main program still is on the C++ side).

**edit to answer subsequent questions in the comments**

As said in the comment of the second `build.rs` below, the name chosen in `.compile("cpp_from_rust")` will be used to name a library containing the compiled C++ code (`libcpp_from_rust.a` for example).
This library will then be used by Rust to extend the Rust code: the `libcpprust.a` main target produced by Rust contains `libcpp_from_rust.a`.

If no C++ file is provided before `.compile()` (as in the first, minimal example below), this C++ library only contains the symbols enabling `extern "Rust"` access from C++.

```
$ nm ./target/debug/build/cpprust-28371278e6cda5e2/out/libcpp_from_rust.a

lib.rs.o:
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T _Z13rust_from_cppv
                 U cxxbridge1$rust_from_cpp
```

On the other hand, you already found in the documentation that multiple invocations of `.file()` are allowed in order to provide the C++ library with much more code from various source files.

Another question was about the kind of library we want Rust to produce.
[This documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/linkage.html) enumerates the various binary targets Rust can produce, especially various kinds of libraries.
Since in your original question you wanted the main executable to be on the C++ side, this means that Rust should produce a library which can be considered as a *system* library, not a Rust specific one, because Rust won't be involved anymore when generating the executable.
In the aforementioned documentation, we can see that only `staticlib` and `cdylib` are suitable for this usage.

In my examples, I chose `staticlib` for the sake of simplicity, but `cdylib` can be used too.
However, it is a bit more complicated because, as the main library (`libcpprust.so`) is generated as a dynamic one, Rust does not insert the C++ library (`libcpp_from_rust.a`) into it; thus, we have to link against this C++ library, which is not very convenient.

```
g++ -std=c++17 -o cpp_program src/main.cpp \
    -I .. -I target/cxxbridge \
    -L target/debug -l cpprust \
    -L target/debug/build/cpprust-28371278e6cda5e2/out -l cpp_from_rust \
    -pthread -l dl
```

And of course, because we are now dealing with a shared library, we have to find it at runtime.

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=target/debug ./cpp_program
```

I don't know whether some other kinds of libraries (`crate-type`) could work (by chance) with this C++ main program or not, but the documentation states that only `staticlib` and `cdylib` are intended for this usage.

Finally, note that if you use `crate-type = ["staticlib", "rlib", "dylib"]`  in `Cargo.toml` (as stated in your comment), you will produce three libraries:

- `target/debug/libcpprust.a` from `staticlib`,
- `target/debug/libcpprust.rlib` from `rlib`,
- `target/debug/libcpprust.so` from `dylib`.

Unfortunately, when linking with the command `g++ ... -l cpprust ...`, the linker will *prefer* the `.so` to the `.a`; you will be in the same situation as `cdylib` above.

---

**The layout of the directory for the minimal example**

```
cpprust
├── Cargo.toml
├── build.rs
└── src
    ├── lib.rs
    └── main.cpp
```

`Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "cpprust"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["staticlib"]

[dependencies]
cxx = "1.0"

[build-dependencies]
cxx-build = "1.0"
```

`build.rs`

```
fn main() {
    // This will consider the ffi part in lib.rs in order to
    // generate lib.rs.h and lib.rs.cc
    // minimal example: no C++ code to be called from Rust
    cxx_build::bridge("src/lib.rs")
        .compile("cpp_from_rust");
}
```

`src/lib.rs`

```
#[cxx::bridge]
mod ffi {
    extern "Rust" {
        fn rust_from_cpp() -> ();
    }
}

pub fn rust_from_cpp() -> () {
    println!("called rust_from_cpp()");
}
```

`src/main.cpp`

```
/*
  Building this program happens outside of the cargo process.
  We simply need to link against the Rust library and the
  system libraries it depends upon

  g++ -std=c++17 -o cpp_program src/main.cpp \
      -I .. -I target/cxxbridge \
      -L target/debug -l cpprust \
      -pthread -l dl
*/

// consider the ffi part of Rust code
#include "cpprust/src/lib.rs.h"

#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
  std::cout << "starting from C++\n";
  rust_from_cpp();
  std::cout << "finishing with C++\n";
  return 0;
}
```

The `cargo build` command will generate the `libcpprust.a` static library in `target/debug`.
Building the main program simply relies on usual commands, provided that we find the relevant headers and libraries (see the comments in the code).

Note that the C++ source code for the main program is in the `src` directory here, but it could have been put anywhere else.

---

**The layout of the directory for the bidirectional example**

```
cpprust
├── Cargo.toml
├── build.rs
└── src
    ├── cpp_from_rust.cpp
    ├── cpp_from_rust.hpp
    ├── lib.rs
    └── main.cpp
```

We just added a pair of `.hpp`/`.cpp` files.

`build.rs`

```
fn main() {
    // This will consider the ffi part in lib.rs in order to
    // generate lib.rs.h and lib.rs.cc
    // The generated library (libcpp_from_rust.a) contains the code
    // from cpp_from_rust.cpp and will be inserted into the generated
    // Rust library (libcpprust.a).
    cxx_build::bridge("src/lib.rs")
        .file("src/cpp_from_rust.cpp")
        .flag_if_supported("-std=c++17")
        .compile("cpp_from_rust");
}
```

Note that this time the build process actually handles some C++ code (see below) to be called from Rust.

`src/lib.rs`

```
#[cxx::bridge]
mod ffi {
    extern "Rust" {
        fn rust_from_cpp() -> ();
    }
    unsafe extern "C++" {
        include!("cpprust/src/cpp_from_rust.hpp");
        fn cpp_from_rust() -> ();
    }
}

pub fn rust_from_cpp() -> () {
    println!("entering rust_from_cpp()");
    ffi::cpp_from_rust();
    println!("leaving rust_from_cpp()");
}
```

`src/cpp_from_rust.hpp`

```
#ifndef CPP_FROM_RUST_HPP
#define CPP_FROM_RUST_HPP

// declare a usual C++ function (no Rust involved here)
void
cpp_from_rust();

#endif // CPP_FROM_RUST_HPP
```

`src/cpp_from_rust.cpp`

```
#include "cpp_from_rust.hpp"

#include <iostream>

// define a usual C++ function (no Rust involved here)
void
cpp_from_rust()
{
  std::cout << "called " << __func__ << "()\n";
}
```

`Cargo.toml`, `src/main.cpp` and the build process (`cargo build`, `g++ ...`) still are the same as in the previous example.

Comment: this is an awesomely written answer, thank you! The main error on my part was not including cxx_build (I didn't think I needed it because I was not invoking C++ code from Rust, but clearly that is not the case). Also, my g++ arguments were incorrect and out of order. Finally, for some reason when I include rlib and dylib in the crate-type argument of Cargo.toml, things do not work (do you know why?).

Comment: Followup question: what happens if I have more than one C++ file to be compiled by Cargo/cxx_build? Do I include two calls to `.file(...)` in `build.rs`? Also, are there any constraints on the name string provided as argument to `.compile`? I am guessing not, and that that is just the name of the intermediary object code file.

Comment: Looking at cc::Build (https://docs.rs/cc/1.0.1/cc/struct.Build.html) I can see yes, we can have multiple `.file` calls. There is even a `.files` method for adding multiple files in a single call.

Comment: @user118967 I edited my answer in order to consider your comments.

Comment: Thanks, really great stuff, you should be a teacher and/or write technical books. :-)

Comment: Its interesting that to go from Rust to c++ the cpp source code has to be in the crate. How would I implement this into an existing code base. Does the entire code base need to be in the crate? How would I reference external c++ files or libs?

Comment: @marsh In the answer, just before the layout of the bidirectional example, you will find that putting C++ source code amongst the Rust code was just a convenience for this short example. If you need to reference external headers or library, you could probably rely on [`CFG`](https://docs.rs/cxx-build/1.0.86/cxx_build/static.CFG.html) or directly use `.flag_if_supported()` (for `-I`, `-L`, `-l`...) in `build.rs`.

Comment: I am getting `#include relative to `.` or `..` is not supported in Cargo builds` when I try to include my headers.

Comment: Also if I use a direct path to force the file to be included, it cant find any of the headers that header includes.

Comment: @prog-fh Do you know if there is a way to combine the static library and the shared library after building using `cdylib` such that you only need to link to a single shared library?

Answer (score 0):

If you are windows and building in VSCode. You might want to add the following to .cargo/config.toml, else the c++ build would complain of mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary'

```
 [target.x86_64-pc-windows-msvc]
 rustflags = ["-Ctarget-feature=+crt-static"]
```